# Nim's Nimble scripts

Tags: nim-lang, nimble-nim

Using npm, one can define scripts inside of `package.json` that can be easily called like

```bash
npm run <script-name>
```

It is very handy to compile/start/lint the project

How are we suppposed to do this with Nimble when using Nim lang?

Answer (score 1):

Found the way, it is called tasks.

You can define any in your `.nimble` file (`nimble init`) like this

```
task greet, "Print a greeting message":
  exec "echo Hello!"
```

You can then call

```bash
nimble greet
```

Answer (score 0):

If environment variable `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is defined, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nim/config.nims` or `~/.config/nim/config.nims` (POSIX) or `%APPDATA%/nim/config.nims` (Windows). This file can be skipped with the `--skipUserCfg` command line option.

`$parentDir/config.nims` where `$parentDir` stands for any parent directory of the project file's path. These files can be skipped with the `--skipParentCfg` command line option.

`$projectDir/config.nims` where `$projectDir` stands for the project's path. This file can be skipped with the `--skipProjCfg` command line option.

A project can also have a project-specific configuration file named `$project.nims` that resides in the same directory as `$project.nim`. This file can be skipped with the same `--skipProjCfg` command line option.

Comment: Please see [how do I format my posts](/help/formatting) and format them correctly. This is rather difficult to read at the moment.